# django bootstrap toolkit not responsive. How to force it to be?

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

Do you know how to force django bootstrap toolkit to be responsive? I mean e.g the change of navbar when width is small.

I have in `base.html`:

```
{% bootstrap_stylesheet_tag %}
{% bootstrap_stylesheet_tag "responsive" %}
```

what is "translated" to when checked in view source of page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-responsive.css">
```

full `base.html` content here: https://gist.github.com/andilab/785133e800f023c89689

example rendered @ jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/andilab/4Jqab/

Comment: Are you including the responsive version of bootstrap? see https://github.com/dyve/django-bootstrap-toolkit/issues/27

Comment: @fasouto When I added `BOOTSTRAP_CSS_URL = 'http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-responsive.css'` to my `settings.py` bootstap seems not working at all.

Comment: Ok, have you added the viewport? `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

Comment: BTW, next time try to provide some more information. It´s difficult to help without it.

Comment: @fasouto this is my base.html https://gist.github.com/andilab/785133e800f023c89689

Comment: here is JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/andilab/4Jqab/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find here the updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/4Jqab/1/

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top"  role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
            <a class="brand" href="/"><img src="http://dogspot.dyndns.org/static/lapa_icon.png">dogspot</a>
           <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
                <li><a href="/dogs" class="">Dogs</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Form</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Forms<b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="/dogs/create">create</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/contact">contact</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Inline</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Search</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Using template</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <li>
                     <form class="navbar-search pull-left" action="">
                      <input type="text" class="search-query span2" placeholder="Search">
                    </form></li>
                        <li><a href="/dogs/create">create</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/contact">contact</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Pagination</a></li>
                <li><a href="">Buttons</a></li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

A couple of things were missed:

- A fluid container for the nav
- You need to specify the collapsible part of the navbar
- A navbar toggle button

See http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html#navbar

Comment: ONE more thing... http://jsfiddle.net/andilab/4Jqab/3/ how to force some resanoable space between navbar and container?

Comment: Maybe you can add some padding to the bottom of the navbar, but I think I't better if you adapt this bootstrap template http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/examples/fluid.html 
It's done by the bootstrap developers

Comment: BTW, maybe the padding is right I delete the comment because of it.